# Applications of Algebraic Topology to urban planning

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, applications

(Soft question) I was wondering if anybody knows of any applications of Algebraic Topology or Topological Graph Theory to Urban Planning/Public Transportation Planning.

¡Thanks!

Comment: You can use it to count the number of overpasses that have to be built if a network of streets is represented by a nonplanar graph.

Comment: Thanks- I was thinking of more complex applications. I understand there is a new field called quantitative urbanization that uses mathematical models to do Urban Design. I was wondering if Topological tools have been used as well.